# Could the participants in 'The Push' be charged with attempted murder?

Tags: united-kingdom, murder, entrapment

[The Push](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5340856/) is a TV show where participants are coerced into committing an intentional act of murder through psychological manipulation. Even though the setup was staged and nobody was in any actual danger, the participants still acted with the belief and intention that their act would cause their victim to die.

At least this is what they claim in the show.

If this claim is true, could the showmakers prevent them from being prosecuted for Attempted Murder by the Crown Prosecution Service?

Comment: Who would be the Complainant (and/or the CPS's main witness)?

Comment: My understanding is that the CPS does not require a complainant in order to prosecute. The knowledge of a crime having being committed is enough justification to charge a perpetrator. As for witnesses  - anyone who's seen the show presumably.